# Is Aruco a good Marker for high precision pose etimation? If so which dictionnary should i use?

Tags: computer-vision, artoolkit, aruco, apriltags, fiducial-markers

I'm currently working on a computer vision project where i need to estimation the pose of a needle in order to assist the surgeon operating it. Needless to say I need an extremly high precision.

I'm currently working on a code the last intern left and he used the aruco fiducial markers for pose estimation.

I've already read some papers and have the feeling that aruco won't be good enough but there seems to be wide variety of dictionnaries who's properties vary a lot.

Are apriltag , s-TAG or ARToolKitPlus better for this application?

Comment: Hey, I am also interested in this question. Do you have any results?

Comment: Hey, if you are a french speaker i advise you to read my internship "paper" https://www.linkedin.com/in/gr%C3%A9goire-kubler-3b5a27157/

The main conclusion was that tag did not fullfill the needs and needed to be backed up by another system such as an accelerometer. Separately, S-tag was the best tag i found.